# ¿Cómo mostrar un conjunto de datos con su cabecera y su cuerpo según característica común?

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

Desde un servido obtengo un arreglo de tipo `JSON` el cual en un nuevo arreglo denominado `list_group` organizo de acuerdo a lo que requiero hacer. Que los datos obtenidos tienen una caracteristica importante, pertenecen a un grupo determinado, entonces los de **Grupo A** los almaceno en dicha sección, así sucesivamente para los próximos grupos encontrados en el servicio obtenido.

**ARREGLO**

```
list_group = [
    {
      name_group: "Grupo A",
      type: "title_header"
    },
    {
      id_clasificacion:'1',
      nombre_equipo:'Chelsea',
      pj_clasificacion:'0',
      pg_clasificacion:'0',
      pe_clasificacion:'0',
      pp_clasificacion:'0',
      dg_clasificacion:'0',
      ta_clasificacion:'0',
      tr_clasificacion:'0',
      jl_clasificacion:'0',
      pts_clasificacion:'0',
      type: 'table_body'
    },
    {
      name_group: "Grupo B",
      type: "title_header"
    },
    {
      id_clasificacion:'1',
      nombre_equipo:'Real Madrid',
      pj_clasificacion:'0',
      pg_clasificacion:'0',
      pe_clasificacion:'0',
      pp_clasificacion:'0',
      dg_clasificacion:'0',
      ta_clasificacion:'0',
      tr_clasificacion:'0',
      jl_clasificacion:'0',
      pts_clasificacion:'0',
      type: 'table_body'
    },
    {
      id_clasificacion:'2',
      nombre_equipo:'Barcelona',
      pj_clasificacion:'0',
      pg_clasificacion:'0',
      pe_clasificacion:'0',
      pp_clasificacion:'0',
      dg_clasificacion:'0',
      ta_clasificacion:'0',
      tr_clasificacion:'0',
      jl_clasificacion:'0',
      pts_clasificacion:'0',
      type: 'table_body'
    },
    {
      id_clasificacion:'3',
      nombre_equipo:'Atlético de Madrid',
      pj_clasificacion:'0',
      pg_clasificacion:'0',
      pe_clasificacion:'0',
      pp_clasificacion:'0',
      dg_clasificacion:'0',
      ta_clasificacion:'0',
      tr_clasificacion:'0',
      jl_clasificacion:'0',
      pts_clasificacion:'0',
      type: 'table_body'
    },
    {
      name_group: "Grupo C",
      type: "title_header"
    },
    {
      id_clasificacion:'1',
      nombre_equipo:'Bayern Munich',
      pj_clasificacion:'0',
      pg_clasificacion:'0',
      pe_clasificacion:'0',
      pp_clasificacion:'0',
      dg_clasificacion:'0',
      ta_clasificacion:'0',
      tr_clasificacion:'0',
      jl_clasificacion:'0',
      pts_clasificacion:'0',
      type: 'table_body'
    },
  ];
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let grupo of list_group">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark mt-3 bg-dark rounded-sm text-light" >
    <span class="navbar-text">
      <strong>{{grupo.name_group}}</strong>
    </span>
  </nav>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-sm mt-4 table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Equipo</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">PJ</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">PG</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">PE</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">PP</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">DG</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">TA</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">TR</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">JL</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">PTS</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Estado</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Opciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td class="text-center">{{grupo.nombre_equipo}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{grupo.pj_clasificacion}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{grupo.pg_clasificacion}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{grupo.pe_clasificacion}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{grupo.pp_clasificacion}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{grupo.dg_clasificacion}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{grupo.ta_clasificacion}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{grupo.tr_clasificacion}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{grupo.jl_clasificacion}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{grupo.pts_clasificacion}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">-</td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
               Detalle
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-1">
               Eliminar
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**LO QUE SE PRETENDE**

Mostrar una cabecera que seccione los datos y una tabla que estrucutre los datos restantes, es decir:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        GRUPO A      |      GRUPO B     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Real Madrid     |     Chelsea      |
|     Barcelona       |  Manchester City |
|     Atl. Madrid     |  Manchester Untd |
```

La información a mostrar no es consecuente con las columnas estipuladas en el código, además hay una sección donde queda en blanco, justo antes de comenzar a estructurar los datos de los equipos deportivos.

> He replicado el problema obtenido en [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtafdc) para que puedan
>   tener una idea mucho más clara en caso tal de que lo dicho
>   anteriormente se quede muy corto.

**LO QUE SE OBTIENE (Stackblitz)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**MÉTODO DEL CÓMO SE ARMA EL ARREGLO**

```
//Recorremos los datos obtenidos
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
      {
        //Evaluamos si el arreglo no tiene datos
        if (this.list_groups.length == 0)
        {
          //Forma a la que tengo que llevar el arreglo
          /*
          [
            {
              grupo: A, 
              equipos : 
              [ 
                {
                  id_clasificacion:'1', 
                  nombre_equipo:'Chelsea'
                }
              ]
            }
          ];*/
          //Empujamos el primer valor para llenar el arreglo
          this.list_groups.push(
            {
              name_group: data[i].nombre_grupo,
              type: 'title_header'
            },
            {
              id_clasificacion:data[i].id_clasificacion,
              nombre_equipo:data[i].nombre_equipo,
              pj_clasificacion:data[i].pj_clasificacion,
              pg_clasificacion:data[i].pg_clasificacion,
              pe_clasificacion:data[i].pe_clasificacion,
              pp_clasificacion:data[i].pp_clasificacion,
              dg_clasificacion:data[i].dg_clasificacion,
              ta_clasificacion:data[i].ta_clasificacion,
              tr_clasificacion:data[i].tr_clasificacion,
              jl_clasificacion:data[i].jl_clasificacion,
              pts_clasificacion:data[i].pts_clasificacion,
              type: 'table_body'
            }
          );
        }
        else
        {
          //Filtramos el arreglo
          let approved = this.list_groups.filter(element => element.name_group == data[i].nombre_grupo);

          //Evaluamos si el arreglo obtuvo un valor vacio
          if (approved.length == 0)
          {
            //Empujamos el valor al arreglo final
            this.list_groups.push(
              {
                name_group: data[i].nombre_grupo,
                type: 'title_header'
              },
              {
                id_clasificacion:data[i].id_clasificacion,
                nombre_equipo:data[i].nombre_equipo,
                pj_clasificacion:data[i].pj_clasificacion,
                pg_clasificacion:data[i].pg_clasificacion,
                pe_clasificacion:data[i].pe_clasificacion,
                pp_clasificacion:data[i].pp_clasificacion,
                dg_clasificacion:data[i].dg_clasificacion,
                ta_clasificacion:data[i].ta_clasificacion,
                tr_clasificacion:data[i].tr_clasificacion,
                jl_clasificacion:data[i].jl_clasificacion,
                pts_clasificacion:data[i].pts_clasificacion,
                type: 'table_body'
              }
            );
          }
          else
          {
            //Empujamos el valor al arreglo final
            this.list_groups.push(
              {
                id_clasificacion:data[i].id_clasificacion,
                nombre_equipo:data[i].nombre_equipo,
                pj_clasificacion:data[i].pj_clasificacion,
                pg_clasificacion:data[i].pg_clasificacion,
                pe_clasificacion:data[i].pe_clasificacion,
                pp_clasificacion:data[i].pp_clasificacion,
                dg_clasificacion:data[i].dg_clasificacion,
                ta_clasificacion:data[i].ta_clasificacion,
                tr_clasificacion:data[i].tr_clasificacion,
                jl_clasificacion:data[i].jl_clasificacion,
                pts_clasificacion:data[i].pts_clasificacion,
                type: 'table_body'
              }
            );
          }
        }
      }
      console.log("Data: ", this.list_groups);
```

Comment: creo que tu JSON deberia tener otra estructura para lo que quieres, algo como :`[{grupo: A, equipos : [ {id_clasificacion:'1',
      nombre_equipo:'Chelsea'}...]...}....]` y si no puedes hacer este JSON, te va a tocar reordenarlo en tu frontend para obtener lo que quieres

Comment: Vale, funciona de la manera que tu me dices, excelente, pero creo que ya la duda que me viene es como empujaría el objeto que coincide con el grupo A a la sección del grupo A, si me hago entender? He adjuntado el código del cómo lo hago.